# SSIS Flat file could not deal with NUL (\x00) value?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, null, etl, flat-file

I am trying to load data from text files to database. My source files contain null character `NUL` somehow (Picture1).

[image: Picture1]

I just make all the fields as one column (delimited with `{CR}{LF}`). Then I　do the preview of the data.

[image: Picutre2]

The data is just what we need. 
But then when I run the package, the data changed, not like what I see in data preview. I added a data viewer to see the data.

[image: Picture3]

[image: Picture4]

The number 1 disappear in the first row (see the red). It seems that flat file reading ends at `NUL` character. But my Row delimiter is `{CR}{LF}`, it doesn't make sense the number 1 in the end disappear. Can anyone tell me why is that?

Comment: Have you tried importing as fixed width? It actually looks like a fixed width file as I don't see any tab characters in your screen grab

Comment: A sample  file (not an image) will greatly help us here, as then we can test against that and try to replicate the the problem and see how we get around it. Those images look like BIDS as well; are you using SQL Server 2008(R2)? Certainly your screenshots looks like Windows XP; which has been out of support for years.

Comment: Oh wait.. This question was asked in 2013. Perhaps @Yahfoufi would have been better asking a new question.

Comment: @Larnu I will try to update the question in a while and to provide a sample file. Also i didn't asked a new question since I am facing the same problem but the file content is different

Comment: Why update someone else's question, @Yahfoufi ? Should this not be a new one? Editing this question (extensively) will hide the original question the initial OP had.

Comment: @Larnu If I posted a new question then certainly it will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Of what, @Yahfoufi? This question isn't a duplicate candidate, as there are no upvoted answers. if you're saying there is a duplicate out there, then you already have the answer. If, however, you've reviewed other questions that are **similar** but didn't answer your question, then reference those in the question and explain why those solutions didn't work; so that we know what you've already tried and tested, and failed to implement (or doesn't work).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the info. I didn't knew that duplicates are considered based on answers. If the bounty ended with no solutions I will ask a new question.

Comment: A question with no answers hardly offers a good duplicate candidate, when the (other) question remains unanswered, @Yahfoufi :)

Comment: @Larnu Lucky me:) All what I needed where mentioned in the answer below!! Now, there is no need for a new question.

Answer (score 4):

### Reproducing the error

First of all, I would like to show the steps to reproduce this error using [Notepad++ editor](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

I created a text file called `TestNUL` that contains data similar to the screenshot posted in the question (commas are placed where `NUL` objects should be):

[image]

Now, Go To Edit menu strip >> Character Panel

[image]

Now the ASCII character panel is shown, double click on the `NULL` value in order to add it to the text:

[image]

Now the text file will looks like:

[image]

You can use the following link to download the file:

- [TestNUL.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c9815ehc98t3cj/TestNUL.txt?dl=0)

### Removing NUL character using Notepad++

To remove this character you can simply open Notepad++, Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace dialog. Then select to use Regular Expressions and replace `\x00` with an empty string:

[image]

All `NUL` characters are removed:

[image]

#### Find and replace in multiple file

If you are looking to find and replace this character in multiple files, then you can use notepad++ to do this using *Find in Files* feature:

- [How to find and replace line(s) in multiple files using Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1003790/how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files-using-notepad)
- [How to Find and Replace Words in Multiple Files](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/)

### Automating the process Within SSIS

Since the issue occurs at run-time not while previewing data, you can simply add a Script Task before the data flow task to replace all `\x00` values with an empty string. You can read the text file path from the flat file connection manager or you can store it in a variable. You can use a similar C# code:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    string FilePath = Dts.Connections["SourceConnection"].ConnectionString;

    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
    text = text.Replace(Convert.ToChar(0x0).ToString(), "");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath, text);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

If you are working with large text files then you can use `System.IO.StreamReader` and `System.IO.StreamWriter` classes to read the file line by line using `ReadLine()` function.

- [How to read a large (1 GB) txt file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net)
- [How can I read, replace and write very large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146573/how-can-i-read-replace-and-write-very-large-files)

#### Experiments

I created a package and added two flat file connection manager, the source reads from `TestNUL.txt` file and the destination create a new `TestNUL_edited.txt` file with the same structure. I added a Script Task with the code above and added a data viewer in the Data Flow Task, the following screenshot shows how the rows are not corrupted:

[image]

[image]

Also the following screenshot shows how the `NUL` values are removed from the source file after running the Script Task:

[image]

### References

- [Notepad++ showing null values after crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816593/notepad-showing-null-values-after-crash)
- [How to Insert a Null Character (ASCII 00) in Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/61742/how-to-insert-a-null-character-ascii-00-in-notepad/1127647)
- [What does \x00 mean in binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954538/what-does-x00-mean-in-binary-file)
- [Find/Replace nul objects in Notepad++](http://security102.blogspot.com/2010/04/findreplace-of-nul-objects-in-notepad.html)
- [Removing "NUL" characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters)
- [How to Find And Replace Text In A File With C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Map every field in his column (using Tab {t} as column delimiter I suppose, and {CR}{LF} as row delimiter) and try again.

Comment: column delimiter　is not necessary, because I don't need to break the rows to a few of columns. I just need it as one column

Comment: in your Flat File Source try to check or uncheck option "Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow"