# Cannot run django server after integrating database

Tags: django, django-models

I am having problems running my server after I try to integrate the database with the application using the "python manage.py inspectdb > /models.py" command.

This is what I have in my models.py file

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#     * Rearrange models' order
#     * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
#
# Also note: You'll have to insert the output of 'django-admin.py sqlcustom [appname]'
# into your database.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_group'

class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'

class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType')
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_permission'

class AuthUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'

class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'

class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_content_type'

class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_session'

class DjangoSite(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_site'

class DjangoUser(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_user'
```

and this is the error message I get

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.comma
nds.runserver.Command object at 0x0000000002CD1518>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

It seems I have a null variable some place but I don't know where that is coming from. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you try to delete `from __future__ import unicode_literals` line and try again?

Comment: nope. That didn't solve the issue.

Comment: It relates to null bytes being inserted into your models.py file. See here for how to remove them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters

Comment: Yeah did that, that didn't change anything for me either

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem myself. I finally fixed it:

- open the generated model.py file in Notepad++ (or other)
- copy/paste the generated code into a new file in IDLE
- Save over model.py

I'm not sure *why* this works, but I got an encoding error trying to open the file directly in IDLE. So I copy/pasted the code, and it fixes everything.

Comment: Like you I have no idea why this worked, but it did. Copied the whole file out of my models.py, pasted it into a new file and saved over and everything went fine after that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Sublime 3 as editor. It got solved if I resaved the models.py file in my app folder as 'Save with Encoding :: UTF-8'.