# Character for NUL

Tags: csv, null, nul

[image]

I'm attempting to ignore a character coming through on CSV documents from a client.

The character is NUL and on a separate final line, I've tried Ctrl + Space and Ctrl + @ (2)? but these don't replicate the symbol, does anyone know what it is and what exactly it does? and/or the keyboard representation for the symbol?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters

Answer (score 0):

`NUL` can be represented by the escape code `\x00`. [Wikipedia article with more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)