# My Javascript file was replaced by a line of null

Tags: javascript, null, notepad++

It's hard to see, but what follows is the top line of my javascript file and its missing all of my code. In place of the code is the word "null" repeated over and over again. Does anybody know why and how this would happen?
[image]

Comment: Potential duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace \x00 characters with regular expressions.
Click Search --> Replace --> Find What: \0 Replace with: "empty" Search mode: Extended --> Replace all