# "NUL" shows in PHP file instead of code

Tags: php

I have a client I am helping out and I've never seen this one before. When I opened up their backup file they got inside some of the files it shows NUL (not to be confused with NULL)

It looks like if the file was maybe binary or something instead just normal PHP code. Any ideas on how the files can be converted back to normal PHP code? The sizes of the files still show as if there is content inside of them.

If it helps - here's a screenshot:

http://screencast.com/t/4K5bexgnL

Comment: They could possibly be corrupted, but couldn't tell unless you gave us a sample file.

Comment: @Matt where can I upload a file so you guys can see? What's acceptable to use in SO?

Comment: @MrTechie now would be a good time to review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see the whole file. We want you to narrow down to the most minimal, complete code that results in this issue.

Comment: @Sean if I try to paste anything it just adds as a "space" and no characters at all. So my own "verifiable example" was to show a screen shot of what I am seeing in the file. Thanks for the pointers tho.

Comment: Try to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19332965/5399527) to remove the `NUL` characters in your file. If you're left with something that isn't PHP code (or possibly nothing at all), we might be looking at a corrupted file.

Comment: try a different text editor like sublime or dreamweaver