# Removing null characters from big files in Windows

Tags: windows, null

I am looking for a quick way to remove null characters from a text file in Windows.
The solution consisting in using Notepad++ and replacing "\0" by nothing in all document [(as described here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters) is not working with very big files. Mine is about 180M and notepad++ is stuck infinitely trying to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for Windows. The idea is to import [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix?rq=1) from UNIX to Windows.

1) Downdload and install [CoreUtil](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) which is a collection of basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities for Windows.

In windows 7 exec files will be typically be installed in 
c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

2) remove NULL characters by running this command in cmd window:

```
tr -d '\000' <input_file >output_file
```

example:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>tr -d '\000' <putty_measurements_1.log >putty_measurements_2.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post, but i think it would be useful for others.
This approach works only if the nulls to delete are on the end of the line (In my case i have lines long 1000+ with 600 characters of null on the end).

Just copy the whole thing, and past it on a new file tab, and automatically notepad will replace all nulls in spaces. Then just save using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to trim all lines.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah!  Wonderfully simple!  And that bit about trimming the lines is important, too.  Thanks for this!  Worked like a charm.  I merged a bunch of vcf files to combine into one big vcf file to copy contacts from my flipphone to google, and google wouldn't take it until I cleaned it up.  I don't know how well this will work for really large files, but for mid-sized ones it will work easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for tools to remove trailing NULLs from big files, and the solutions I found didn't work with 1GB+ files or took ages. Therefore I designed my own in C#, which works pretty well, and here it is:

```
private void CopyContentsUntilNull(string source, bool keepFileDate = true)
{
    string destination = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(source)}{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source)}_fixed{Path.GetExtension(source)}";

    var sourceDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(source);

    int bufferSize = 10000;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int nullCount = 0;
    int readCount;

    using (var srcStream = File.OpenRead(source))
    using (var dstStream = File.OpenWrite(destination))
    {
        do
        {
            readCount = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            int bytesToCopy = FindTrailingNull(buffer, readCount);

            if (bytesToCopy > 0)
            {
                if (nullCount > 0)
                {
                    var block = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, nullCount).ToArray();
                    dstStream.Write(block, 0, nullCount);
                    nullCount = 0;
                }
                dstStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToCopy);
            }

            nullCount += bufferSize - bytesToCopy;

        } while (readCount == bufferSize);
    }

    if (keepFileDate)
        File.SetLastWriteTime(destination, sourceDate);
}

private int FindTrailingNull(byte[] buffer, int readCount)
{
    for (int i = readCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (buffer[i] != 0)
            return i + 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Beware that some files already have NULLs at the end, like zip files (from 2 to 4), so you might need to add some at the end until it works. The same applies to docx, xlsx, etc. as they are also zip files.