# Why is the r code changed to be unrunnable after I renamed the file in windows explorer?

Tags: r

After I renamed the r-file in windows explorer (ending was not changed) and open the r file in the RStudio again, the code added these red dot between every single characters as shown below.

[image]

I can not copy out the red dot to do a find/replace.

Are there any solution to this problem? Why does this happen?

I run RStudio on Windows 10.  I am using the newest version now.

Comment: If here is not the right place to post the question: where should I post this question?

Comment: If you open your code in a text editor does it have the same display issues?

Comment: That looks like an encoding issue.  It appears something changed the encoding to UTF-16, but RStudio is reading it as though it is some 8 bit encoding.  You could use "File | Re-open with encoding..." in RStudio to try to find one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in text editor, then refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332949/removing-nul-characters), will solve the problem.